# Python: large XML parsing with multiple children of root tree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Need to parse the large XML file with python (xml.etree.ElementTree) to process and generate a report as shown in expected section.

I can't figure out how to get down until 4th level for certain details and from there into 5th level for it's respective/associated data. Where to loop and how to reference the children, is my problem. Please give any suggestions that you may have, thank you.

```
Input XML File: raw_data.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<FirstLevel Flevel="my1">
    <SecondLevel Slevel="my2">
        <ThirdLevel Tlevel="my3">
            <FourthLevel test="1" mydata="Needed1">
                <FifthLevel associated="Required for Needed1"/>
            </Fourthlevel>  
            <FourthLevel test="2" mydata="Needed2">
                <FifthLevel associated="Required for Needed2"/>
            </Fourthlevel>  
            <FourthLevel test="3" mydata="Needed3">
                <FifthLevel associated="Required for Needed3-1"/>
                <FifthLevel associated="Required for Needed3-2"/>
            </Fourthlevel>  
            <FourthLevel test="4" mydata="Needed4">
                <FifthLevel associated="Required for Needed4-1"/>
                <FifthLevel associated="Required for Needed4-2"/>
            </Fourthlevel>  
        </ThirdLevel>
    </SecondLevel>
</FirstLevel>
-----------------------------------------------------------

My Code:

    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('raw_data.xml')
    root=tree.getroot()
    mylevel=root.findall('.//FourthLevel')
    for i in mylevel:
        print ("mydata=",i.get('mydata'),"\t")
        assoc=root.findall('.//FifthLevel') ### assoc: Temporary variable for associated data
        for j in assoc:
             print ("associated=",j.get('associated'),"\n")




Output: final_output.txt

mydata=Needed1  associated=Required for Needed1
mydata=Needed2  associated=Required for Needed2
mydata=Needed3  associated=Required for Needed3-1
mydata=Needed3  associated=Required for Needed3-1
mydata=Needed4  associated=Required for Needed4-1
mydata=Needed4  associated=Required for Needed4-1
```

Comment: Instead of `root.findall('.//FifthLevel')`, try `i.findall('FifthLevel')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already iterating *root*'s child nodes, having the name *".//FourthLevel"*. You just have to apply the same principle for each child and its children having the name *"FifthLevel"* (notice the *slash*es missing).

Translated to code, you just need to replace the line:

```py
assoc=root.findall('.//FifthLevel')
```

by:

```py
assoc = i.findall("FifthLevel")
```

as you need the 5<sup>th</sup> level child only for **current** node (4<sup>th</sup> level), not for the whole tree. Check [[Python 3.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) for more details.

Comment: You should probably mark the answer as a solution to the question then (if you're allowed to - considering that the question is dupe).